# SQLite Queries are not updating the XML layout at runtime

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a basic food log where people can enter the food name and the calories in the editTexts:

[Layout Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS0dd.png)

The onClick method should take their input and add to the the database, and then run a query to retrieve the list of foods and add it back to the layout, as well as getting the total calories.

In the main activity:

```
// Add a food to the database
public void onClickAdd(View view) {
    // Get the food stats from the layout
    String foodName = txtFood.getText().toString();
    String calString = txtCalories.getText().toString();
    int calories = Integer.parseInt(calString);

    Food food = new Food(foodName, calories);
    // Add the new food (the name and the calories)
    foodDBHandler.addProduct(food);

    // Setting the new values in the textviews
    printDatabase();
    getTotalCalories();
}

public void printDatabase(){
    String dbString = foodDBHandler.databaseToString();
    txtFoodLog.setText(dbString);
    txtFood.setText("");
}

//Get the total calories
public void getTotalCalories() {
    int dbString = foodDBHandler.sumCalories();
    txtTotalCals.setText("Total Cals: " + dbString);
    txtCalories.setText("");
}
```

The FoodDBHandler class runs the queries in which printDatabase() and getTotalCalories() use:

```
// Gets a list of all the foods
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FOOD + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    Cursor recordSet = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    recordSet.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!recordSet.isAfterLast()) {
        // null could happen if we used our empty constructor
        if (recordSet.getString(recordSet.getColumnIndex("foodname")) != null) {
            dbString += recordSet.getString(recordSet.getColumnIndex("foodname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        recordSet.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}

public int sumCalories(){
    /*
    This method goes through the entire db, then checks if there are empty values in the food column
    If the column is not null, then it takes the calorie value of the food and adds it on to the dbString value (which is an integer despite the name)
    */

    int dbString = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FOOD + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in the results
    Cursor recordSet = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    recordSet.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!recordSet.isAfterLast()) {
        // null could happen if we used our empty constructor
        if (recordSet.getString(recordSet.getColumnIndex("foodname")) != null) {
            dbString += recordSet.getInt(recordSet.getColumnIndex("calories"));
        }
        recordSet.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

The problem is that when I hit the onClickAdd button, the text just disappears from the layout without sending back the information from the table.

Is it the way I'm updating the content or the database itself?

Comment: Do you actually have any data in the table? I'd suggest eliminating this by adding `Log.d("DBToSTRING`,"Extracted Cursor has " + Integer.toString(recordSet.getCount()) + " rows.");` after line `Cursor recordSet = db.rawQuery(query, null);` and running. If it's 0 then perhaps it's your `addProduct` method that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is some problem in query

```
 String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FOOD + " WHERE 1";
```

Ideally, you have to provide column_name in the query

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FOOD + " WHERE QUANTITY = 1";
```

Comment: **`WHERE 1`** will return **all** rows. **`WHERE`** basically takes the result true or false from the following expressions. 1 equates to true, thus all rows.

Answer (score 0):

As the cause of your issues could be numerous here's an example App that works. However, instead of using what appears to be a TextView to display the list of foods, it uses a ListView.

Although not a specific answer, the intention is to provide a working example that may highlight issues and thus answer the issue.

### MainActivity.java :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtFood, txtCalories;
    Button mAddFood, mDeleteFood, mBack;
    ListView mFoodListListView;  //<<<< ListView rather than text with new lines
    TextView txtTotalCals;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;   // <<<< Cursor Adapter for the ListView
    Cursor mFoodListCursor;     // <<<< Cursor to populate the ListView

    FoodDBHandler fh;           // <<<< DB Helper (CAN't BE INSTANIATED YET)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get Views form thier ID's
        txtFood = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.et_food);
        txtCalories = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.et_calories);
        mAddFood = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_addfood);
        mDeleteFood = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_dltfood);
        mBack = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        mFoodListListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.foodlist);
        txtTotalCals = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.caloriecount);

        // Instantiate the FoodHandler instance
        fh = new FoodDBHandler(this);

        // Load the Listview with data if any.
        mFoodListCursor = fh.getAllFoods();
        mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                mFoodListCursor,
                new String[]{ FoodDBHandler.COL_FOOD_NAME, FoodDBHandler.COL_CALORIES},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},
                0);
        mFoodListListView.setAdapter(mSCA);
        txtTotalCals.setText(fh.getTotalCalories());

        //Set the Button click listeners
        setAddFoodButtonListener();
        setDeleteFoodButtonListener();
        setBackButtonListener();
    }

    private void setBackButtonListener() {
        mBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("BACKBUTTONCLICK","The back button was clicked.");
                // finish(); commented out as this main activity
            }
        });
    }

    private void setAddFoodButtonListener() {
        mAddFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (txtFood.length() < 1 || txtCalories.length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Unable to Add - Blank Value(s).",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                    return;
                }
                fh.addFood(
                        txtFood.getText().toString(),
                        Integer.valueOf(txtCalories.getText().toString()));
                refreshListView();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setDeleteFoodButtonListener() {
        mDeleteFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (txtFood.length() < 1 || txtCalories.length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Unable to Delete - Blank Value(s).",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                    return;
                }
                String foodname = txtFood.getText().toString();
                long caloroies = Long.valueOf(txtCalories.getText().toString());
                long id;
                if ((id =fh.getIdFromNameAndCalories(foodname,caloroies)) > 0) {
                    if (fh.deleteFood(id)) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Deleted.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show();
                        refreshListView();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Oooops not Deleted????",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Unable to Delete - Not Found.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void refreshListView() {
        mFoodListCursor = fh.getAllFoods();
        mSCA.swapCursor(mFoodListCursor);
        txtTotalCals.setText(fh.getTotalCalories());
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- As this is the main activity/initial activity back button has been disabled. Typically the finish() method would be called by an invoked activity that returns to the invoking activity. You don't typically do this in the main activity as there is no invoking activity.
- Deleting Foods will not delete a food/calorie combination if there are multiple identical combinations (adding allows this as written).

### FoodHandler.java :-

```
public class FoodDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "foods";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_FOOD = "food";
    public static final String COL_FOOD_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_FOOD_NAME = "foodname";
    public static final String COL_CALORIES = "calories";

    Context mContext;
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    FoodDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mContext = context;
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crttblsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                TABLE_FOOD +
                " (" +
                COL_FOOD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_FOOD_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COL_CALORIES + " INTEGER " +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crttblsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Gets a list of all the foods <<<< NO LONGER USED
    public String databaseToString() {
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FOOD + " WHERE 1";

        //Cursor points to a location in your results
        Cursor recordSet = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //Move to the first row in your results
        recordSet.moveToFirst();

        //Position after the last row means the end of the results
        while (!recordSet.isAfterLast()) {
            // null could happen if we used our empty constructor
            if (recordSet.getString(recordSet.getColumnIndex("foodname")) != null) {
                dbString += recordSet.getString(recordSet.getColumnIndex("foodname"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
            recordSet.moveToNext();
        }
        //NOTE! no cursor.close() SHOULD ALWAYS CLOSE A CURSOR WHEN DONE WITH IT
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }

    // Example of how databaseToString could be written <<< NOT USED
    public String altDatabaseToString() {
        StringBuilder dbString = new StringBuilder();
        Cursor recordset = mDB.query(TABLE_FOOD,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        int columncount = recordset.getCount();
        while (recordset.moveToNext()) {
            dbString.append(recordset.getString(recordset.getColumnIndex(COL_FOOD_NAME)));
            if (recordset.getPosition() < (columncount - 1)) {
                dbString.append("\n");
            }
        }
        recordset.close();
        return dbString.toString();
    }

    // <<<< Equivalent to addProduct
    public boolean addFood(String food, int calories) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_FOOD_NAME,food);
        cv.put(COL_CALORIES,calories);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_FOOD,null,cv) > 0;
    }

    // <<<< deleteFood according to id column
    public boolean deleteFood(long id) {
         return mDB.delete(TABLE_FOOD,COL_FOOD_ID + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}) > 0;
    }

    // <<<< get the id column according to name and calorie columns
    // NOTE! will only allow return of id if there is no ambiguity
    // i.e. name/calorie combination must be unique
    public long getIdFromNameAndCalories(String foodname, long calroies) {
        long rv = -1;
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TABLE_FOOD,
                null,
                COL_FOOD_NAME +
                        "=? AND "+
                        COL_CALORIES +
                        "=?",
                new String[]{foodname,String.valueOf(calroies)},null,null,null);
        // Ambiguous as extracted multiple rows i.e. which one to delete????
        if (csr.getCount() > 1) {
            return rv;
        }
        if (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_FOOD_ID));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    // <<<< Uses SQL features to get the sum of the calories
    public String getTotalCalories() {
        String rvcolumn = "caloriecount";
        String rv = "0";
        Cursor csr =mDB.query(TABLE_FOOD,
                new String[]{"sum(" + COL_CALORIES +") AS " + rvcolumn},
                null,null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = Integer.toString(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(rvcolumn)));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    // <<<< Simply get all rows from the database
    public Cursor getAllFoods() {
        return mDB.query(TABLE_FOOD,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- There are some redundant methods with comments indicating as such.
- Of course the structure of the table has been based upon assumptions.

### activity_main.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="so.com.so48101940food.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_food"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:hint="Your Food"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_calories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Calories"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_record"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/foodlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/caloriecount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10">
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_addfood"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_dltfood"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### Example Screen Shots :-

- Initial (first run) :-

[image]

- Added 1 Food :-

  - ListView is populated.
  - Calorie count is adjusted.
  - Delete would delete and revert to previous screen.

[image]

- Added multiple Foods :-

[image]